# Game Center tvOS closes after scrolling leaderboard

Tags: game-center, tvos, game-center-leaderboard

I managed to get my leaderboards up and running on tvOS.
But I have a very strange issue. I have 37 leaderboards and when you begin scrolling on the Siri remote, after about 20 leaderboards Game Center closes.

I get the following output

```
2016-01-26 11:56:18.429[216:14842] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension interrupted
2016-01-26 11:56:18.432 [216:14842] plugin com.apple.GameCenterUI.GameCenterDashboardExtension invalidated
2016-01-26 11:56:18.458 [216:14625] Finished
2016-01-26 11:56:19.525 [216:14625] viewServiceDidTerminateWithError:: Error Domain=_UIViewServiceInterfaceErrorDomain Code=3 "(null)" UserInfo={Message=Service Connection Interrupted}
```

Comment: Also when performing an interrupt while in Game Center windows, upon returning to the game, Game Center freezes.

Comment: The issue only appears when you add over 30 leaderboards.